# How to make frozen column in primeNg scrollable

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable, frozen-columns

How can we make the frozen column in the primeNg table scrollable? I want an individual scroll on the frozen column. How can we achieve that?
Stackblitz link attached.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablescroll-demo-sxjgmj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Do you want to be able to scroll the frozen name column independently of the rest of the table? That seems like a strange UX pattern.

Comment: Yes, I want to scroll the frozen column independently. While I also want scroll functionality to work as it is with other columns as well.